# compile directly from vim

Tags: c++, vim, compilation

I'd like to compile cpp file w/o turning off vi.
I know the **:!g++ file.cpp** but I prefer **:make** so I added this line in .vimrc file

> au FileType C set makeprg=gcc\ %
>   au FileType Cpp set makeprg=g++\ %

but I keep getting 
"make: ***** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.** "message.
can anyone tell me what is wrong with my setting?
I use to compile successfully with the option above.

Comment: make searches a file named Makefile in your current directory. May be that's the problem? I'm a makefile-newbie myself, so it's just a guess.

Comment: I don't know the inside action of what "au FileType CPP set makeprg"
but I compile w/o Makefile from another server. I don't understand why I fail to compile in my own computer
I'm using Ubuntu 8.10

Comment: I've never heard of :make concerning vi. Is it an improvement of vim?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I should change **C,Cpp** into **c,cpp**, then it works fine.
thank you all, especially **Rob Wells**, your answer helped me a lot. thank you.

Comment: Also change `set` to `setlocal` in order not to override default setting for other filetypes.

Answer (score 10):

You need the substitution there, try something like:

```
set makeprg=gmake\ %:r.o
```

Oh, this assumes that you've got:

1. a (M|m)akefile in the directory, or
2. default SUFFIX rules are available for your environment (which it looks like there aren't)

Check for the default by entering:

```
make -n <my_file>.o
```

and see if that gives you something sensible.

If there is a makefile in another location you can add the -f option to point at the makefile, for example:

```
set makeprg=gmake\ -f\ ../some_other_dir/makefile\ %:r.o
```

BTW For learning about make, and especially gmake, I'd suggest having a look at the excellent book "Managing Projects with GNU Make" ([sanitised Amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596006101)).

HTH.

cheers

Comment: I find out what my problem was. it was about case of C,Cpp.
I should change it into c,cpp. but your answer was very helpful.
Thank you.

Comment: @Luc, ?? Or is $*.o a new vim makeprg syntax?

Comment: $* is not a new &makeprg syntax element. It has always been there (with :make). It will get replaced with make target. All is needed then, is a mapping that will use the current %<, or another variable value as :make target.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's much easier if you write a Makefile and put it where vi can find it. I'm not sure if you actually use vi (I've only used Vim), but when there is a Makefile compiling should be as easy as writing **:make** (no set makeprg needed).

Comment: thank you for your answer. but I use the editor for very smallprojeccts like project euler problems.
so everytime I write a code, making Makefile is quite irritating. that's why I am trying to use the :make(direct compile).

Answer (score 5):

It can be easily achieved by the use of key maps.

First open up your vimrc file and these lines to the file,

```
autocmd filetype cpp nnoremap <F4> :!g++ % -ggdb -o %:r <CR>
autocmd filetype cpp nnoremap<F5> :!g++ % -ggdb -o %:r && ./%:r <CR>
```

The first line maps the key F4 to **compiling the file**. The second line maps the key F5 to **compile and run**.

If you use gdb frequently then this may also come handy.

```
autocmd filetype cpp nnoremap<F10> :!g++ % -ggdb -o %:r && gdb -tui %:r <CR>
```

This line maps the key F10 to **compile and start gdb**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend a vim plugin called SingleCompile instead of what you have done:
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3115

Answer (score -5):

First of all, just make the bloody make file. Every tool out there is expecting to work with make and if your compilations are that simple it takes about 30 seconds to write a make file that compiles all c and cpp files into an executable.

Second, if you refuse to use a make file then try

```
:help system
```

That should give you enough info to come up with your own command similar to this

```
:com Mymake call system("g++ ".expand("%"))
```

Comment: Why do you think it is better than `:!g++ %`?

Comment: @MariusGedminas Good question. And I imagine all the negative votes are party due to the nerdrage in beginning of the answer, which is hardly professional or welcome on SO. :P